# get current time without page refresh

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I would like to get the current time without page refresh. However, the following code is only able to update the time by refresh manully.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

**currentTime.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "test.php",
               success: function(msg){
                 $("#results").append(msg);
               }
             });
        });
<p id="results"></p>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
   $CT = date('Y:m:d H:i:s', time());
   echo $CT;
?>
```

Comment: You don't actually need to make this work with a ajax unless you need to get the specific server time. You can achieve this with javascript new Date(); and setInterval();

Answer (score 1):

This will change the time each second, with the `setInterval` you pass the amount of miliseconds that the interval will be called. So at the moment, each second.

```
function getTime(){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "test.php",
           success: function(msg){
             $("#results").append(msg);
           }
         });
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    getTime(); 
    setInterval(getTime, 1000); // Get time each second
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit overkill, but here's my idea. Instead of overloading the server using many ajax-calls. Do the following:
1. Do a ajax-call, return the timestamp and multiply it with 1000 (milliseconds)
2. Start a counter based on the ajax-call timestamp

Might require some more coding, but it's a far better solution when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loop_time = 2000 ; /*  mean 2 Second */
    var html_tag  = 'body' ;  /* You Can Use # or . or default */
    var php_page  = 'test.php' ; 
    setInterval(function() {
          $(html_tag).load(php_page);
    }, loop_time);
});
```

i didn't try it :) , You Can Try It